# Public Key Pinning not working

Tags: apache, http-headers, public-key, pinning

Hello I am trying to implement Public-Key-Pinning on my apache server running as a proxy for another web-app, but it won't work (if I enter a wrong hash the page is still displayed instead of an error, which should be shown in Firefox or Chrome). I am sure the header is correct – the hash is correct, I have tested it with Chrome.

My Configdata is

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName subdomain.*******.***:443
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/___.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/___.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/___.ca
Header always set Public-Key-Pins "pin-sha256=\"****\"; pin-sha256=\"****\";  max-age=120; includeSubDomains"

    <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / ****:****/
    ProxyPassReverse / ****:****/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

At first I only had one hash but I added a second one just in case this would be required. What am I doing wrong?

Note: Of course I have mod_header enabled and loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two hashes are required and they must be two independent hashes. I.e. You cannot pin the cert and the intermediate cert that issued that as they are not independent. This is a safety feature to ensure you have a backup incase you need it.

Additionally a policy will only be accepted if it passes so you cannot put in a fake policy and watch it fail because it will never be accepted.

A good tool to check your policy is this one: https://report-uri.io/home/pkp_analyse
And also other tools on same site to actually generate your policy:
https://report-uri.io/home/pkp_hash

However you need to be VERY careful with HPKP. It's very easy to block your website and, hope you don't take this the wrong way, it doesn't sound like you fully understand HPKP so I would suggest you read about it some more first.

There is a Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only (which is only available in Chrome at present) , and which allows you to test a policy for a bit (well in Chrome at least) but for that you also need to use the report-uri option (you can also use above site to collect your reports if you don't want to write your own service for this).

I've an active interest in this and, if people don't mind me linking here, I've blogged about it in much more detail here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/security/http-security-headers/hpkp/. I think it's potentially a very dangerous option that needs careful consideration before implementing.

Comment: I am sorry if it seems like that I didn't understand HPKP because I have in face been informing my self about it quite a lot lately... but I don't work with servers a lot. As you can see my `max-age` ist at 2 minutes – so I don't lock my server right aways.
I must have missed the part with the two hashes. Thank you – I will look at your resources.

Answer (score 0):

It in fact worked... my mistake was the way I tested it.

So here's the most important thing I missed out:

1. You need at least one backup pin
2. If you test it don't change the hash in the header but either the SSL-Certificate or (better) try changing the hash saved locally. Or thanks for `BazzaDP` for pointing it out try using https://report-uri.io/home/pkp_analyse.

Please read BazzaDP's answer if you are new to HPKP and want to get started with it. Mozilla also has some good documentation.

Comment: @BazzaDP Sorry, I actually wanted to accept my answer... but I guess your one deserves it more

Comment: Also we need to keep in mind that browsers will not accept the HPKP header if the certificate of the web server that we are using is self signed. For testing purposes we can create a Certificate Authority (CA) locally, add it to the browsers trusted list of CAs and sign the certificate of the web server that we are testing using the created CA.